# SOAP to XML conversion and sending it in response object

Tags: java, xml, soap, httpurlconnection, java-metro-framework

I am new to webservices,some how i managed to host a service with metro.With the help of SOAP UI and also **httpUrlConnection** object i am able to get SOAP response.But my next task is to send a response with content type "application/xml".So i used httpServletResponse,but i am not getting how to extract only XML part(without SOAP envolope and SOAP header) and also how to send XML inside respose object.Whether the way in which i am doing is rite?If yes,how to proceed with next step.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to send xml content within SOAP response. To keep wsdl and xsd simple, you may use CDATA for your xml content and parse like a string on the receiving end.

```
 <![CDATA[YOUR XML GOES HERE]]>
```

If you want to parse SOAP message and extract XML then you may want to use Java API [SAAJ](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/WebServicesHowTo#saaj-client)